# how to develop a custom UICollectionViewLayout that has staggered columns with self-sizing cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on the iOS version of an app I already developed on Android. This app has the following 2 column grid of self-sizing (fixed width but variable height) cells:

[image: Staggered 2 column layout on Android]

Achieving this in the Android version was easy because Google provides a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for its `RecyclerView`. You specify the number of columns and the direction of the scroll and you are done.

The default `UICollectionView` layout `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` doesn't allow the staggered layout I'm looking for, so I have to implement a custom layout. I have watched 2 WWDC videos that talk about this topic ([What's New in Table and Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#226) and [Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#232)) and I more or less have an idea of how it should be implemented.

**Step 1.** First an approximation of the layout is computed.

[image]

**Step 2.** Then the cells are created and sized with autolayout.

[image]

**Step 3.** Then the controller notifies the of the cell sizes so the layout is updated.

[image]

My doubts come when trying to code these steps. I found a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) that explains the creation of a custom layout with staggered columns, but it doesn't use autolayout to obtain the size of the cells. Which leaves me with the following questions:

**In step 2, how and when can I obtain the cell size?**

**In step 3, how and when can I notify the layout of the changes?**

Comment: Hi as per your question you can create [UICollectionView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/ ).
But for creating custom [UICollectionViewLayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) with [self-sizing cells](http://corsarus.com/2015/collection-view-with-self-sizing-cells/).

Answer (score 5):

I want to point out that, as you have mentioned, [RayWenderlich PinInterest Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) is exactly the tutorial that'll help you achieve this layout.

To answer your questions - with regards to the tutorial:

**In step 2, how and when can I obtain the cell size?**

To get the cell height, a delegate method was implemented that was called in the `prepareLayout` method of the custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. This method is called **once** (or twice, I just attempted to run it with a `print` statement, and I got two calls). The point of `prepareLayout` is to initialize the cell's `frame` property, in other words, provide the exact size of each cell. We know that the width is constant, and only the `height` is changing, so in this line of `prepareLayout`:

```
let cellHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!,
      heightForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
```

We obtain the height of the cell from the delegate method that was implemented in the `UICollectionViewController`. This happens for all the cells we want to show in the `collectionView`. After obtaining and modifying the height for each cell, we cache the result so we can inspect it later.

Afterwards, for the `collectionView` to obtain the size of each cell on screen, all it needs to do is query the cache for the information. This is done in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method of your custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class.

This method is called automatically by the `UICollectionViewController`. When the `UICollectionViewController` needs layout information for cells that are coming onto the screen (as a result of scrolling, for instance, or upon first load), you return the attributes from the cache that you've populated in `prepareLayout`.

In conclusion to your question: **In step 2, how and when can I obtain the cell size?**

**Answer:** Each cell size is obtained within the `prepareLayout` method of your custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and is calculated early in the life cycle of your `UICollectionView`.

**In step 3, how and when can I notify the layout of the changes?**

Note that the tutorial does not account for new cells to be added at runtime:

> Note: As prepareLayout() is called whenever the collection view’s layout is invalidated, there are many situations in a typical implementation where you might need to recalculate attributes here. For example, the bounds of the UICollectionView might change – such as when the orientation changes – or items may be added or removed from the collection. These cases are out of scope for this tutorial, but it’s important to be aware of them in a non-trivial implementation.

Like he wrote, it's a non trivial implementation that you might need. There is, however, a trivial (very inefficient) implementation that you might adopt if your data set is small (or for testing purposes). When you need to invalidate the layout because of screen rotation or adding/removing cells, you can purge the cache in the custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to force `prepareLayout` to reinitialize the layout attributes.

For instance, when you have to call `reloadData` on the collectionView, also make a call to your custom layout class, to delete the cache:

```
cache.removeAll()
```

Comment: And they are, according to what I've written and according to the tutorial. All the size calculations are done in `prepareLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is not a complete answer, but some pointers regarding your steps 2 and 3 may be found in the subclassing notes for `UICollectionViewLayout`.

I presume you have subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` since off the top of my head I believe this is a good starting point for making adjustments to the layout to get the staggered appearance you want.

For step 2 `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(_:)` should provide the layout attributes for the self sized cells.

For step 3 your layout will have [`shouldInvalidateLayoutForPreferredLayoutAttributes(_:withOriginalAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/shouldInvalidateLayoutForPreferredLayoutAttributes:withOriginalAttributes:) called with the changed cell sizes.

Answer (score 1):

[image: First example of custom layout]

**In step 2, how and when can I obtain the cell size?**
You need to calculate height of each cell in **prepareLayout()** method. Result of calculation for each cell should be assigned to **UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes** variable, and than put it into collection NSDictionary, where key would be NSIndexPath(of each cell), and value would be UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes variable.

Example:

```
- (void)prepareLayout {
    [_layoutMap removeAllObjects];
    _totalItemsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    _columnsYoffset = [self initialDataForColumnsOffsetY];

    if (_totalItemsInSection > 0 && self.totalColumns > 0) {
        [self calculateItemsSize];

        NSInteger itemIndex = 0;
        CGFloat contentSizeHeight = 0;

        while (itemIndex < _totalItemsInSection) {
            NSIndexPath *targetIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIndex inSection:0];
            NSInteger columnIndex = [self columnIndexForItemAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath];

            // you need to implement this method and perform your calculations
            CGRect attributeRect = [self calculateItemFrameAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath]; 
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *targetLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:targetIndexPath];
            targetLayoutAttributes.frame = attributeRect;

            contentSizeHeight = MAX(CGRectGetMaxY(attributeRect), contentSizeHeight);
            _columnsYoffset[columnIndex] = @(CGRectGetMaxY(attributeRect) + self.interItemsSpacing);
            _layoutMap[targetIndexPath] = targetLayoutAttributes;

            itemIndex += 1;
        }

        _contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width - self.contentInsets.left - self.contentInsets.right,
                                  contentSizeHeight);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to implement following methods:

```
- (NSArray <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *layoutAttributesArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in _layoutMap.allValues) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(layoutAttributes.frame, rect)) {
            [layoutAttributesArray addObject:layoutAttributes];
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributesArray;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return _layoutMap[indexPath];
}
```

These methods would be triggered once you call reloadData() mehtod or invalidateLayout().

**In step 3, how and when can I notify the layout of the changes?**
Just call self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() and prepareLayout() method would be called once again, so you can recalculate all parameters you need.

**You can find my full tutorial about custom UICollectionViewLayout here**: https://octodev.net/custom-collectionviewlayout/

Tutorial contains implementation in both languages: Swift and Objective-C.
Would be more than glad to answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The "cell size" is defined by UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute in the layout subclass which mean you can modify it every time you have the chance to touch them. You can set every attributes' size to what you desire.

For example you can do it in layoutAttributesOfElementsInRect(:) , calculate the right size and config all attributes before pass them to collectionView. You can also do it in layoutAttributeOfItemAtIndexPath(:) ,make the calculation when every attribute is created.

Furthermore, consider to provide the desired size by a datasource so every attribute can easily get their size with their index.

For if you want to have the cell size to layout the subviews in a cell, do it in the collectionView delegate method: collectionView:ItemAtIndexPath:

Hope this help.