# UICollectionViewCell With 2 column grid and dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to have collection view with 2 column but dynamic height.
I have used Autolayout and given required constraints to the Cell

By this way I can calculate the dynamic height but its column grids fails.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MenuListCollectionViewCell
       cell.frame.size.width = collectionView.frame.width/2
    cell.menuList = self.menuList[indexPath.row]
    let resizing = cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel)
       return resizing
}
```

This is how I want it to look

[image]

Comment: I guess what you need is staggered layout. Check this if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32398232/5923606.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "its column grid fails".

Anyway, you need to write a custom collection view layout. The default one (UICollectionViewFlowLayout) allows you to change height of the cells by providing the `sizeForItemAt`, but that won't change the behavior of the layout that will always arrange cells in rows of the same height (the height of the highest cell).

If I understood correctly, you just want the same layout of [this raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest).

Basically:

1. Create a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` implementing it's methods:
2. `collectionViewContentSize`: return width and height of the collection view content
3. `prepare`: where you can calculate the sizes of cells and
   collectionView content
4. `layoutAttributesForElements`: where you
   return an array of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` in the given
   rect
5. `layoutAttributesForItem`: where you return the same kind
   of attributes, this time specific for an item
6. assign an object of this class to the collection view layout property

Comment: I hv tried that Raywenderlich’s tutorial, it gives me 2 column cells which u expect but dynamic height fails in that case. Updated question with screenshot of behaviour I expect. Please check.

Comment: You keep saying that it fails, but I don't really understand what do you mean with that. If you could explain maybe I can help. Anyway I don't see what is dynamic in your screenshot. All the cells look pretty much the same height... or am I missing something? PS: it could be useful if you showed your current state in comparison to what you want to achieve.

Comment: in prepare() how can I calculate actual cell's height?

Comment: the method you used is the one to calculate size based on constraints

Comment: now I tried same given in Raywenderlich’s tut but problem is there height is passed according to the image. How that can be done in my case. ? How can I get the view’s height.

Comment: as I said, `yourView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height` should give you the correct height if you set up the correct constraints on the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

This code is somehow written that you can change section inset or minimumInteritemSpacing and this calculate and resize with this parameters

you can use this code or download project from [Github](https://github.com/sadeghgoo/collectionViewFlowLayout)

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let numberofItem: CGFloat = 2

        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.width

        let extraSpace = (numberofItem - 1) * flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

        let inset = flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.sectionInset.left

        let width = Int((collectionViewWidth - extraSpace - inset) / numberofItem)

        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve your desired outcome by doing the following.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 5), height: 100)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = customCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "test", for: indexPath)

    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    return cell
}
```

Make sure you have implemented all the correct delegates

- UICollectionViewDelegate
- UICollectionViewDatasource
- UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

where you see height: make it your own desired height as you have specified in your question.

KEY: Make sure in your storyboard you have set the `estimate size` of the collection view to NONE -> otherwise the code will not work as expected

[image]